# cellForRowAtIndex is taking time to load cell from xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a Custom UITableView class With Xib.

In My `-cellForRowAtIndex` following code is written.

The issue is that it takes 2-3 Sec to Push The screen which contains this `TableView`.

```
       (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"myCell";

        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


        if(!indexPath.row)
        {
         UIView *separatorView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,14, ScreenWidth-40, 1)];
            separatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4 alpha:0.6];
            [cell addSubview:separatorView];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        else
        {
            UIView *separatorView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,6, ScreenWidth-40, 1)];
            separatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4 alpha:0.6];
            [cell addSubview:separatorView];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }

        tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        return cell;
}
```

I have debug the code When I return `numberOfRows` 0 then My screen pushed immediately. Even If I return 1 row then it takes 2-3 sec to load.

I am Creating `tableView` Programmatically.

**Edit**

I have added this in my `viewDidLoad` just after creating my Table:

```
   UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
    [mTableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
```

and CellForRowAtIndex Method:

```
  CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        if(cell == nil){

            cell = (CustomCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
            [cell setRestorationIdentifier:@"myCell"];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        }
```

But NOthing Chaneged

Comment: If you use `registerNib:` then you need to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. And then you need to remove the `if (cell == nil)` block.

Comment: can you please show us your cell implementation file

Answer (score 0):

you need to register the loaded nib once with that reusing identifier so that the table view can deque with that identifier, currently dequeing with identifier is alltime returning nil i guess.

The best place is to register the nib is in the `viewDidLoad` using

```
[self.tableView registerNib:cellLoadedFromNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
```

Then access it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` using the following

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**Make sure you are registering the nib in the tableView after the tableView is been initiated.**

Comment: wait i will modfy my answer

Comment: Not only you should register your nib on `viewDidLoad`, you should also use the dequeue method that has an `indexPath` parameter at the end.

Comment: Exactly, you SHOULD register it whenever you create your `tableView` and use the dequeue method that has the `indexPath` parameter at the end.

Comment: check the answer @RahulMishra i have modified it

Comment: Please note @EmilioPelaez 's good comment.  But I still don't see why switching to the new style of nib loading is the solution.  The old way shouldn't cause a 2-3 sec latency.

Comment: @danh what is the best way

Comment: @RatulSharker see I updaed my question After you answer

Comment: @EmilioPelaez registering nib doesn't solves my issue

Comment: You are only reading half of my advise... As I've already said twice, you also have to use this method to dequeue `- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Comment: @RahulMishra - I just corrected this answer to use the newer dequeue method that goes along with the newer registerNib.  This is the right way to do it now, but I don't see how this could be the correct answer.  Your older approach to building the cells should still work and should *not* take 2-3 secs.

Comment: I agree with @danh, Rahul, are you performing any long synchronous operations in the cell, like network requests?

Comment: does removing the datasource of the tableview also taking so much time ? @RahulMishra

Comment: @RatulSharker No When I remove datasource method then their is no delay..all works fine

Comment: so thats for sure that, something delayed happening in the table view data source protocols

Comment: hey, there is another mistake, use deque reusing identifier @"myCell", your are using nib name, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If this is taking as long as you claim, it's possible that the issue is that you're not doing the `[tableView reloadData]` on the main thread.  You can fix this by calling `[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]` where you are currently calling the `reloadData` method.

Comment: thats wrong, he's getting his cell's loaded, but it just taking time, if the `reloadData` was called in any background thread, then cell's were never loaded.

Comment: His complaint reads that the tableview's cells are taking an inordinate time to push to the screen (not load).  If he isn't reloading the data on the main thread, that's exactly what will happen.

Comment: pushing the screen means loading that particular viewcontroller is taking so much time, because of main thread is blocked

Answer (score 0):

u write code  in -cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

which load on main tread and in every cell load main view's background set number of times

write code in -viewdid load